# JavaScript selector not recognised though works in test

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

My script to replace the logo upon scroll works here in the test 'http://jsfiddle.net/timsalabim/opek5mtz/`

```
var img = document.querySelector('.logo_h__img img'); // get the element
img.dataset.orig = img.src; // dataset 
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) { // add the event listener
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0) { // check the scroll position
        img.src = img.dataset.scroll; // set the scroll image
    } else {
        img.src = img.dataset.orig; // set the original image back
    }
});
```

It does not work when implemented exactly the same way in to the website, I think I have tested it correctly and it is firing too....

I put the script in to my site in the    tags located in the header.php file (Wordpress website) inside these tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    </script>
```

I also didn't forget to add this section the image tag:

```
data-scroll="http://"
```

Is it possible that the navigation is set up in a way that the logo which is nested next to it doesn't recognise a scroll?

**** UPDATE **** Here is my dev site: http://dev.greenlabit.com.au/Test/

If it works in my test it should just work on the dev site...

Comment: There is an error in browser console `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Also on dev site where is the code for scroll?

Comment: I just refreshed it, it's in the head section commented "<!-- SCROLLING SCRIPT --> "

Comment: This function causing error `cherryFixedParallax` on your webpage,on jsfiddle this is not exists that's why it runs successfully there.Try to debug error on that function and run again

Comment: The relevant code is commented out in your dev site so it does not run.

Comment: @BeingSunny Thank you!! I saw this popup when I scroll but couldn't figure out what is going on....

Comment: Check if the plugin is included for the `cherryFixedParallax`.

Comment: Apologies for being so naive but where do I check this, surely it's not just a plugin in Wordpress as there is nothing listed in there.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to run your website firebug gives error on line

```
jQuery("#fixedparallax_header").cherryFixedParallax({
```

Error says :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

---

```
cherryFixedParallax();
VM353:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: cherryFixedParallax is not defined
cherryFixedParallax({});
VM356:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: cherryFixedParallax is not defined
```

Comment: You will need to run website through firebug. On the console panel of firebug you can see this error and under sources tab you will find this error underlined in red. 
Also, I could not find your scrolling logic anywhere on the website, make sure you have it in there.